# Dict arguments that contain a subclass are not handled by Mypy correctly

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, type-hinting, mypy

I have the following example piece of code

```
from typing import Any, Dict


class P:
    pass

class C(P):
    pass

class A:
    def __init__(self, x: Dict[P, Any]):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x: Dict[C, Any]):
        super().__init__(x)
```

When running mypy on it, this warning appears:

> **Argument 1 to "**init**" of "A" has incompatible type "Dict[C, Any]"; expected "Dict[P, Any]"**

Why is this happening? If I do the same, but without using `Dict[]`, ie:

```
class P:
    pass

class C(P):
    pass

class A:
    def __init__(self, x: P):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x: C):
        super().__init__(x)
```

I get no complains. I tried using `Mapping[]` instead of `Dict[]` but the same warning occurs. How can I approach this? Is it a Mypy bug? Shall I mention it as an issue in the Github page?
This happens a lot in the code, as I am subclassing from a Library class, I cannot use cast every time, it's counter productive

Comment: I posted it also at Github issues https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9738

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the mutable containers are invariant. This is not a bug, it's working as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that covariant mapping types may not be available, see discussion here: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/445

Comment: Yes thank you, I have gotten a similar response by posting the issue in Github... I moved on to refactor my code, as currently `mapping` supports only covariant values and not keys